# Indicator Functions properties in Probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory

This is probably quite a straightforward question but I just thought I should double check my working. Say for instance we have two fixed values $K_{1}$ and $K_{2}$ such that $K_{2} > K_{1}$ and that we have a third variable $S$ which changes with time. Then if we have two indicator functions as follows:

$\mathbb{1}_{S \geq K_{1}}\mathbb{1}_{S \geq K_{2}}$

and take the expectation of this, we should get:

$\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{1}_{S \geq K_{1}}\mathbb{1}_{S \geq K_{2}})$

which then turns into the joint probability:

$\mathbb{P}(S \geq K_{1},S \geq K_{2})$

but since $K_{2} > K_{1}$ this means we can write the probability as

$\mathbb{P}(S \geq K_2)$

right? Sorry if this is trivial, I don't have anyone to check my work with so I'm quite paranoid about getting some of the minor details wrong :/

Comment: That's correct. Another way to see this is to note that $1_A1_B=1_{A\cap B}$, and in this case $\{S\geq K_1\}\cap \{S\geq K_2\}=\{S\geq K_2\}$.

Comment: Thanks heaps for the prompt reply! Actually writing it your way helps a lot more, I should keep that in mind in the future.

Comment: I believe another way to see this is $P(S\geq K_1, S\geq K_2) = P(S\geq K_1|S\geq K_2)P(S\geq K_2) = 1\cdot P(S\geq K_2) = P(S\geq K_2).$

Comment: @probablyme If $P(S\ge K_2)=0$, this is entering and exiting dividing-by-zero territory, without necessity.

Comment: @Did I thought there might be a problem. Thanks for the information!